# footer isn't sticking in wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sticky-footer

I know this has been posted several times, but I might have made a mess of my code here, and need some help in tangling it out.

I want to make a sticky footer inside the wordpress theme i have styled.
For the sticky footer i have been using this tutorial:
http://www.wordimpressed.com/wordpress/put-a-css-sticky-footer-in-your-wordpress-theme/

I was hoping someone could firebug it and tell me what the issue is.

Here is a link to the website I'm building with problems and all:

http://www.lufter.dk/test/wordpress/

Comment: use this link instead, the problem is much more clear here:
http://www.lufter.dk/test/wordpress/om-sonhks/

Comment: You have Javascript errors on your page, possibly stopping other functions... Check you JS console

Comment: Done. Still not doing anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add CSS:

```
body, #wrapper { height: 100% }
```

then it will work... (on http://www.lufter.dk/test/wordpress/om-sonhks/ )

Comment: It did!
It just hit me that my wrapper was wrapping the whole thing, including my footer.
Fixed it by moving my divs around a bit. Thanks for replies.